# How to implement CMS in meteor

Tags: meteor, azimuth, froala

I have been able to search for the following methods to implement CMS in meteor.

[Yogiben](https://atmospherejs.com/yogiben/admin)
[froala](https://atmospherejs.com/froala/editor)
[orion](http://orion.meteor.com)

I want to do simple content management by creating an admin user. Which of these should I implement is there any other better than these?Can Azimuth be implemented like this, help would be appreciated.I am new to meteor.Thanks in advance

Comment: Try Houston https://atmospherejs.com/houston/admin

Comment: Froala is not what you are looking for. Cut that from your list.

Comment: The aforementioned Houston is a good solution if you need an Admin interface. It works pretty dang well. You can use Collection2 in order to create a schema and validation checks for your collections to prevent any weird mishaps with a user accidentally changing a string to an integer or removing a required field.

Comment: https://github.com/gterrono/houston